# Nikon D5300 Freezing?

Tags: nikon

Sometimes when I am taking pictures, or record 60FPS video only, the camera will simply freeze, and if switched off, it won't respond and display what was on the screen right before it freezed. The only way to fix it is to take out the battery... Does anyone know why or how it does this and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using another SD card with your camera?

Comment: I doubt that's the problem as the speed of the current SD card is 48 megabytes/second, but I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have been using mine for months with no issues. I then went into the sun one day and it froze consistently every 30 seconds when recording 1080p 60fps

Comment: @CalvinMoss Haven't been recording lately, but it could possibly be a slow SD card. Never really 'fixed' it, just haven't noticed it happen lately.

Comment: @CMOS I just had the same problem. Indoors I have no problem. The second I'm out in sunlight it freezes after 5-10 seconds of video. Is this possibly to protect the camera/sensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the SD card.

The camera will first put data into memory / a buffer, then from there, write to the card. If the camera is recording data at a rate that is faster than the card can write, then eventually the buffer will fill. At this point the camera becomes unresponsive. When you turn the camera off, it is still writing out the buffer to the SD card.

Even if your card reports 48 megabytes/second, pay careful attention to whether this is a guaranteed minimum speed. You will probably find it is a peak, or maximum speed, and maybe only for reading from the card, not writing to it. I wrote a summary article on my business website [here](http://wildlifemonitoring.com.au/index.php?module=wiki&page=SecureDigitalCards), if interested.

You wrote that you never really fixed it, but that it hasn't happened lately and that you agreed it may have been a slow card. Did you try alternate cards?